# PHP string splitting

Tags: php, string

I'm new to PHP. I was reading this: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php however I'm looking for additional clarification.

I know in python I can call .split("...") as well as in Java.

So I found chunk_split, str_split, and explode. What are the reasons for using each? From what I was reading I was under the impression that each could be used for the same task. Is there an explicit advantage for using one over the other?

I'm looking to split a url to get the "Base" (not sure what else to call it)

Ex:

> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I was thinking I could cut off the front with if statements

```
if = http:// or http://www. or www. etc... #pseudo
```

Then cut by "/" chars and take the front.

Which function is best purposed for this?

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Along with `basename()`.  Not sure if you want the deepest dir or the domain name.

Comment: @AbraCadaver can you explain that? I would like the domain name. Ex stack overflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're after is [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';

$parsed_url = parse_url($url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($parsed_url);
echo '</pre>';
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.stackoverflow.com
    [path] => /questions/ask
)
```

Comment: It's a typo, the important stuff is there.

Comment: @bali182: I'm well aware that it's a typo, the answerer should take more care with what they post.

Comment: I agree Blue Dog, thanks for pointing it out. I actually got pulled away from my desk right at the moment I'd normally review my answer and make edits, so there was nothing I could do. :P